# HTML-PHP Mail Form | Hide Server Information

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I hide server information when I send a mail from my mail form? Screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46445635/php%20mail.png

Mail form link is: blogsoc.org/mail
and my mail.php code is:

```
sorry the code has been deleted
```

Please tell me the necessary changes. And also. Can I get that "Thank You! Your mail has been sent." message be shown in the same page instead of opening another page?

Comment: Can you post the server information you wish to hide? Not everyone can access your link (most importantly, me). :-)

Comment: It's gator1449.hostgator.com :) site: http://blogsoc.org/mail

Comment: By "post" I meant in the question text.

Comment: That is gator1449.hostgator.com near to Name, Email. Check out the screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46445635/php%20mail.png

Comment: ***I can't view the screenshot. I have IP filters in my office.***

Comment: Okay. It looks like this "from:  Angry Birds admin@blogsoc.org via gator1449.hostgator.com" :)

Comment: You might have to contact your SMTP host for that. This may be an anti-spam measure.

Comment: To be true. I want it to work like: http://emkei.cz/

Comment: So... you want to do an anonymous mailer right?

Comment: Yes. I will be making it bulk mail sender which can send HTML mails.